# .NET: Will copying an array to itself have a performance impact?

Tags: arrays, .net, .net-core

I already know that [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy) can be used with the same array in both the source and the destination, even if they overlap.

But what if these overlapping elements are actually the same? I know that the array<s>s</s> will not change, but will it affect performance?

Take this as an example:

`Array.Copy(x, 0, x, 0, x.Length);`

If I have an array of 1 million elements, will they still be accessed and copied to themselves? Or is the runtime smart enough?

Comment: Why would you do this? The runtime can only do what it's programmed to, so someone would have to anticipate this use case in order to program the runtime to optimize it.

Comment: What happened when you ran that code?  Did it work?  Did it take a long time?

Comment: This happens in the CLR, and isn't specified in the language spec or the documentation, so it is an implementation-specific detail.  The [framework code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,305) doesn't perform such a check, though.

Comment: If you need to know you can look at the source, but it might be easier to just test it out. https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/array.cs

Comment: Slack, I checked it, but the reference source points to an internal call. 

Comment: And Servy, my code is not ready to run yet. I was just asking.

Comment: Follow the rabbit. It's good practice.

Comment: @TheodoreTsirpanis  You've already written the code.  There's only one line of code to test, and it's right in your question.  You don't need to run any of the rest of your code to test what the array copy will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I doubt the runtime is smart enough to detect this unusual scenario, but I haven't done anything to validate that assumption.

While it's good to consider the possible impact of this I wonder if it's a case of premature optimization--are you asking because you know, for a fact, that your code will be given huge arrays of largely identical items, or because you think there's a chance of it.

In general it's best to keep your code simple--don't try to prevent every hypothetical corner case.  Use tools such as profilers to understand if this code is *too slow* (not just slow--but slow enough to be a problem).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for my situation, my code moves array elements to its beginning by calling `Array.Copy(arr, ofs, arr, 0, len);`, and sometimes, `ofs` becomes zero, and `len` becomes equal to `arr.Length`. The array is small; usually less than 1000 elements, so I will not optimize for this particular case (which might occur frequently in my problem) before I profile first to be sure.